# An email address that automatically responds based on received messages

Tags: exchange

I should say I am a complete beginner to Exchange Server, so please bear with me. I want to set a specific email with basic responding functionality;  Here is an illustrating scenario:

After a learning session, participants would like to know each others by keeping contacts (emails). Generally this is easily done if the organizer has the list of participants already, he can send an empty mail to all so that participants know about each other. This has two drawback because the organizer has much work to-do writing each email address, and the second drawback is that people not willing to share their emails need to declare so.

The other solution would be if anyone "wanting" to share his/her address with others also willing to do so, anyone would send a mail with basically a random number determining the session (in email object or content). The business mail receiving all these will gather all and after some time (say 5 minutes), re-diffuse the list of mails to each of them the other way around.

Is this little intelligence feasible in Exchange Server ? This would be very helpful.

I put this question in SO then moved it here, since I have no starting point.

Comment: The correct way to do this is for the participants to swap email addresses if they wish to do so. Then you are out of the loop.

Comment: Because It would ease the process. Being out of the loop would be better in one way: if some would like to share only to other some, then one-to-one share is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach isn't solvable by just using Exchange. You will have the rely on a third party solution or just write a program/script yourself. Your first approach by relying on manual labor is probably less of a headache. For option number two you'd have to communicate how that system works.

If you do include the preference of sharing data in your initial sign up for the lesson it would also be easier to write a script that just shares that data after the session finishes.

Comment: OK @Seth, writing a program could be a solution, do you have an entry point at Exchange server documentation?

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't start the official documentation. [Microsoft Docs Exchange](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/)

Comment: so much in there; but yes, there is no better starter.

Comment: I found about Mail flow rules in Exchange Server. This seams feasible this way. I will invest more time when I install an instance and proceed.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/mail-flow-rules?view=exchserver-2019

Comment: Mailflow rules aren't what you're looking for. You will most likely have to setup a mailbox you can receive "signup" mails in and write a script that will evaluate the content of the mailbox. Setting up "open" distribution lists might also be feasible. In all likely hood your solution will tie into the sign up for lessons.